# Tableau : Create a calculated column which adds up all the values of another column

Tags: tableau-api

I have the data in tableau like this

```
City     Number of office   Total Offices     
Chicago     5                  20
Houston     6                  20
Dallas      4                  20
```

I want to create a calculated field which has the difference of value [Total Offices] -(minus) Sum([Number of Office]). It should look like this
(20 - (5+6+4)) =  5

```
City     Number of office   Total Offices      Difference(Calculated Field)  
Chicago     5                  20               5    
Houston     6                  20               5    
Dallas      4                  20               5
```

How can achieve this

Comment: What does this even mean? What is total offices and where does it come from? Why is it different from the total of "number of office"? Are you trying to get the difference between a subset and a global total?

Answer (score 1):

simply this

```
[Total Offices] - {sum([Number of Office])}
```